# Python QtDesigner and Update of Form after GPIO Event on Rasberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, qt-designer

i am new to python and i am struggeling with the following Problem:
i designed a form with QTDesigner (some Buttons and a Textfield).
Converted the .ui to a .py file anded imported it to my main.py

Whne i press a button, a vraiable is updated and the textfield is changing.
So far it works fine. But when i add a GPIO Event, which calls a function, the variable also is changed, but the Textfield is not updating....

I am not sure what i mak wrong or where the Problem is (passing the arguments ?...diffrent thread ?...)

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from display import Ui_MainWindow

entercodestring=""
```

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

```
locked=26

def __init__(self):

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(Main.locked, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Main.locked,GPIO.RISING, bouncetime = 200, callback = self.buttonEventHandler)

    #GUI
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)        
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.ui.pushButton_0.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_0_clicked)
    self.ui.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_clicked)
    self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2_clicked)
    self.ui.pushButton_back.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_back_clicked)


def buttonEventHandler(self,channel):
    global entercodestring
    entercodestring = "Closed"
#Problem is here textDisplay is not showing the new string
    self.textDisplay.setText(entercodestring)

def pushButton_0_clicked(self):
    global entercodestring
    entercodestring = entercodestring + "0"
    self.ui.textDisplay.setText(entercodestring)

def pushButton_1_clicked(self):
    global entercodestring
    entercodestring = entercodestring + "1"
    self.ui.textDisplay.setText(entercodestring)

def pushButton_2_clicked(self):
    global entercodestring
    entercodestring = entercodestring + "2"
    self.ui.textDisplay.setText(entercodestring)


def pushButton_back_clicked(self):
    global entercodestring
    entercodestring = entercodestring[:-1]
    self.ui.textDisplay.setText(entercodestring)

def pushButton_enter_clicked(self):
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution. 
First i need to create a pyqt signal and emit it....
This emited signal then can be connected lika a button_click event.